# Find the index position of an array?

Tags: java

Hi i wrote this method to return the index position of an array, but I keep getting 0 as the return value. Can anybody tell me why?

```
public static int indexPosition (int [] intArray, int x)
{
    int index = 0; 

    for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++)
    {
        if ( intArray[i] == x)
        {
            index = i;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

this is the part of the main method using this method

```
 for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) 
    {
        System.out.println(names[i] + ": " + times[i]);
        System.out.println(indexPosition(times, i));
    }
```

Comment: What are the values of `intArray` and `x` when you call this method?

Comment: Two conditions are there ..   There is no match, or the match happened at first element itself  . You can break the look when match finds

Comment: Two possibilities: either the 0 position in the array was a match, or else there was no match (`index` is initialized to 0, so you will get 0 back if there is no match). Perhaps you should initialize `index` to -1? Then you will know there was no match, because it's not possible a match would produce -1 as a result.

Answer (score 2):

Change your default value from `0` (a valid index), to `-1` (so your caller can know that the array didn't contain the element). Also, there doesn't seem to be a purpose to storing the value (just return the matching index, if there is one). Something like,

```
public static int indexPosition (int [] intArray, int x) {
    for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
        if (intArray[i] == x) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: it is still giving me -1, i think that means something is wrong with the way I am entering my parameters

Comment: You're testing for the numbers `0` to `names.length` (why do you think your array `times` contains 0,1,2,3 or `n` - where `n` is `names.length - 1`)?

Comment: @ElliotFrisch, isnt 0 to names.length the same thing as 0,1,2,3,4,5 ...n where n is names.length?

Comment: @ziggy You are looking for the index of i in times. Since you are getting -1 than it doesnt exist. Change it to `System.out.println(indexPosition(times, times[i]));`

Comment: @ziggy What is the result of `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(times))`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch "there doesn't seem to be a purpose to storing the value" This depends on if the intent is to return the first or last of duplicate matches.

Comment: @LINEMAN78 Thanks that did it!